# Is a game engine actually needed to make games?

Tags: software-engineering

I see Game engines like Ogre are just software wrappers or software systems to enable easier access to certain features provided by other programmers that are relevant to game development.

However, isn't it true that no game engine is needed to program games at any scale?

Comment: If you have a computer or [a stick and a large beach](http://xkcd.com/505/), you can make anything. The rest of this seems to be a philosophical question: What's a game engine? If I write a function that abstracts over rendering hexagons in an OpenGL window, is that a game engine? (It would already cover much of [*Super Hexagon*](http://superhexagon.com/).)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. There is no need to use an engine to make your game. But in many cases it's just a matter of "why reinvent the wheel?"

There are for example frameworks such as lib gdx that abstracts away the most low level OpenGL stuff, so that you can focus on the things that actually matter.

I really recommend this blogpost by Dennis Gustafsson to get an insight in to what frameworks and engines does for you! It also gives some insight into what you really have to do if you want to cram out the last bit of performance from the hardware you are working with, which often is the reason some people stay away from "real engines". http://tuxedolabs.blogspot.se/2013/01/development-environment.html

With all this said, if it makes you excited to write things from the ground up, you should absolutely try it!